# dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal for - openshot

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I am getting following error while trying to run `sudo apt upgrade`

**Update:**

If I try to remove `libopenshot-audio7` via `sudo apt remove libopenshot-audio7` following error shows.

> (Whatever I am trying with `apt` this error shows whether remove,
> install or upgrade)

```bsh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopenshot20 : Depends: libopenshot-audio8 but it is not installed
 python3-openshot : Depends: libopenshot-audio8 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So then I ran `apt --fix-broken install` after that following error is showing

```bsh
(Reading database ... 284777 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libopenshot-audio8_0.2.1+dfsg2+139+202108251944~ubuntu20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopenshot-audio8:amd64 (0.2.1+dfsg2+139+202108251944~ubuntu20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libopenshot-audio8_0.2.1+dfsg2+139+202108251944~ubuntu20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenshot-audio.so.0.2.1', which is also in package libopenshot-audio7:amd64 0.2.0+dfsg2+139+202108251703~ubuntu20.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libopenshot-audio8_0.2.1+dfsg2+139+202108251944~ubuntu20.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```bsh
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Did you do an apt update before the apt upgrade?

Comment: @David `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`

Comment: You may have to remove `libopenshot-audio7` first, as there are conflicting files.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I tried but it shows same error. I have updated the question. If there any ways to remove that package please do let me know :)

Comment: The Ubuntu 20.04 repositories include neither `libopenshot-audio7` nor `libopenshot-audio8`. You are not using a version of Openshot provided by Ubuntu. In other words, you created the problem for yourself by going outside the Ubuntu repositories. One solution is to uninstall ALL non-Ubuntu Openshot packages, and install the tested, compatible Ubuntu version instead. If you wish to continue using the non-Ubuntu version, your question should include details on your install method and deb sources -- you're asking us to do a bunch of research for you, so you need to help with a starting point.

Comment: @user535733 I got the point Thanks :) now if i want to remove any non-ubuntu package how can i do that? I am getting error while removing any package by using `apt remove package_name`!  I am stuck here. Pls help :(

Comment: Wrong question. You already know that all your Openshot packages are non-UBuntu. You should be asking "*How do I remove all openshot-related packages?*" Try `apt autoremove openshot --simulate`  to see what such a removal would look like. Advice: Learn to love the `--simulate` flag before you muck up your system even worse.